# How to extract the 3 vectors from a given sparse matrix?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sparse-matrix

I can use the vectors data, row_ind and col_ind to create a sparse Matrix with the function sparse.csr as follows:

sparse.csr_matrix((data,(row_ind,col_ind)),[shape=(M, N)])

However, assuming that I have a sparse Matrix A as my input; how do I extract the data, row_ind and col_ind vectors?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which programming language does this belong to? Can you add the appropriate tag?

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out. The sparse matrix has to be created With sparse.dok_matrix() and then the values can be extracted with the method values()

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.dok_matrix.html

It does not work with sparse.csr_matrix() and sparse.csC_matrix() since the method values()is not available for them